# How to use scp in a bash script and wildcards

Tags: bash, ubuntu, scp

I have a bash script to retrieve files from remote server with scp.

My script looks like this:

```
read -p 'Enter pattern: ' VAR_DATE

SCPUSER='user'
SCPHOST='server.de'
SCPDIRECTORYREMOTE='/some/directory/remote'
LOCALDIR='/my/local/directory/somewhere'

scp $SCPUSER@$SCPHOST:"$SCPDIRECTORYREMOTE/test.txt" $LOCALDIR
scp $SCPUSER@$SCPHOST:"$SCPDIRECTORYREMOTE/*_$VAR_DATE.pdf" $LOCALDIR
```

Unfortunately, only the first file (test.txt) get downloaded. By all the other files where I use the wildcard (*) I get the error `scp: /some/directory/remote/*_MY_PATTERN No such file or directory`

I tried many [solutions suggested](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27419/how-to-use-wildcards-when-copying-with-scp) using single and/or double quotes.

No one worked so far. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE
Here is the output of `bash -x`

```
+ read -p 'Enter pattern: ' VAR_DATE
Enter pattern: dffff
+ VAR_DATE=dffff
+ SCPUSER=user
+ SCPHOST=server.de
+ SCPDIRECTORYREMOTE=/some/directory/remote
+ LOCALDIR=/my/local/directory/somewhere
+ scp user@server.de:/some/directory/remote/test.txt /my/local/directory/somewhere
test.txt                                                                                       100% 2120    77.8KB/s   00:00    
+ scp 'user@server.de:/some/directory/remote/*_dffff' /my/local/directory/somewhere
scp: /some/directory/remote/*_dffff: No such file or directory
```

Comment: The error message looks malformed, though not *exactly* in the way it would be malformed if you passed in a string which ends with a DOS carriage return. Can you provide a `bash -x` transcript of an example run?

Comment: Where's your suffix `.pdf` in your debug code?

Comment: And why do you believe there should be files matching this pattern? For all we can tell the error message is simply stating an unescapable fact.

Comment: The files are there. When I use the same scp command directly in the console, it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect an issue with local globbing. And this looks like an excellent place to use `tar` and `ssh`. Something like,

```
ssh $SCPUSER@$SCPHOST "tar czf - $SCPDIRECTORYREMOTE/*_$VAR_DATE*" \
    | tar xvzf - -C $LOCALDIR
```

Comment: Is the minus after xvzf a typo?

Comment: @codyLine Good question! It is not. That indicates read from stdin (after `xvzf`) and write to stdout (after `czf`). See also Unix Power Tools [10.13 Copying Directory Trees with tar and Pipes](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix3/upt/ch10_13.htm) - **note** tweaking the `tar` command should allow you to transfer all relevant files with one command.

Comment: It's not working. I get the following error `tar: /some/directory/remote/*_dffff: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors`